# In SQLAlchemy, why can I still commit to the database after closing a session?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with Postgres, for the first time. After doing the dance of

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://localhost/test', convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False,
    autoflush=False,
    bind=engine
))
```

I ran code to add some stuff to the `test` database, and after that, I issued a `db_session.remove()` command (and `.close()` for good measure). Yet, I was still able to query and modify the tables in the `test` database. If removing the session doesn't affect its functionality, what's the purpose of removing it? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scoped_session` is a special factory object.  Accessing methods such as `query()` creates a session.  One session exists per scope, so the same session will be used each time `query` (for example) is accessed.  Calling [`remove()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.remove) will remove the session and the next attribute access will create a new session.

Calling [`close()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.close) on a session will release the connection resources associated with it.  They will be re-acquired when the session is used again.

`close()` and `remove()` are "temporary", they don't make the session unusable in the future.  Typically, you do not need to `close` or `remove` a `scoped_session`, it will be managed automatically.